# I got "AttributeError: World instance has no attribute 'fire' " while executing below code. what should i do?

Tags: python

```
class World(DirectObject):

    def __init__(self):
      ..........................
      ..........................
      ..........................
      if (self.keyMap["fire"] !=0 and task.time > task.nextBullet):
        self.fire(task.time,self.panda.getPos(), self.panda.getHpr(), bulletSpeed, bulletLife) 
      ........................
      ........................
      ........................
      ........................
      def fire(self, time, pos, hpr, speed, life):
            self.node = World.sphere.copyTo(render)
            self.node.setPosHpr(pos, hpr)
            self.speed = speed
            self.life = life
            self.alive = True
            self.bullets.append(self.node)
        return task.cont
w = World()
run()
```

Comment: First thing you should do is fix the indentation in your question so that what is displayed matches what you actually have. It looks like `def fire` is inside the `__init__` function.

Answer (score 2):

Is `def fire(...)` at the same level of indentation as `def __init__(...)`?
If not, there lies the problem.

In the code you posted, `fire` is being defined as a plain function inside the `__init__` method (which just so happens to have `self` as its first argument).